# Cast class type retrieved from string

Tags: swift, generics, casting, swift2

I'm trying to read a class from a String and pass its type to a generic function. But it seems like there's no way to achieve this:

```
protocol Person { ... }
class Student: Person { ... }
class Teacher: Person { ... }

func foo<SomePerson: Person>(param: String, type: SomePerson.Type) { ... }

// Get class from string and pass class type to foo()
let someClass = NSClassFromString("MyApp.Teacher")
foo("someParam", type: someClass.dynamicType)
```

Trying this I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot invoke 'foo' with an argument list of type '(String, type: AnyClass.Type)
```

Is it actually possible to obtain the 'real' type 'Teacher' instead of the generic type 'AnyClass' and pass it to foo()? The classes are read on runtime from a file - so using hard class names when calling foo() is not possible.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: if you know the real type already use that one instead without the ugly `NSClassFromString` - if you do not know the type, then how can you be sure it is a subclass of Person?

Comment: I don't know the real type ... the class name (MyApp.Teacher in the example above) is read from a file. The types stored in the file are always going to be types subclassing Person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If `Person` is a class as the original question was written:*

Since you are making the life for the compiler considerably harder that it needs to be you have to help him a bit. You have to make sure the type is correct before calling the function:

```
if let actualType = someClass as? Person.Type {
    foo("someParam", type: actualType)
} else {
    // error handling here
}
```

Which yields the desired working code:

[image]

---

*If `Person` is a protocol:*

You are going to have a bad day. The above solution will not work. As far as I can remember your only option is to check for every possible subclass:

```
if let actualType = someClass as? Student.Type {
    foo("someParam", type: actualType)
} else if let actualType = someClass as? Teacher.Type {
    foo("someParam", type: actualType)
}
// etc.
```

Comment: Already tried helping the compiler, which results in _Cannot invoke 'foo' with an argument list of type '(String, type: Person.Type)_

Comment: @kinkee are you sure you used the same exact code? It works fine for me

Comment: sorry i had a typo in my example source - 'Person' is a protocol, not a class. Using Person as a class would work, unfortunately theres no option to change the protocol.

Comment: @kinkee well, that is not really a typo but a whole different issue / situation now.

Comment: Yep, that's what I've expected. So I'm going to have to check for every conforming type manually. Thanks for answering.